# Гугл формы - как вывести динамические сообщения исходя из выбранных ответов пользователем?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-forms

Нам нужно сделать форму, где пользователи выбирают определенное значение и ему выдает сообщение или как угодно с определенной инфой, связанной с этим значением после отправки формы.

К примеру, у нас в гугл таблицах планируется сделать два столбца - товар и описание этого товара.

```
Молоко - белое
Банан - желтое
Абрикос - оранжевое.
```

Человек выбирает "Молоко", отправляет форму и ему выдает сообщение "Белое".
Как это реализовать?